# How to check range for width with less mixin ?

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm using the less mixin which generate a random number, here is the code:

```
div{
 background:#FCFCFC;
 margin: 0;
 width : @random;
}
```

The problem here is that the @random variable increase more than it should. I even tried to limit it but then it mess with layout more.

Is there a way constraint the range on @random?

Comment: Not sure what mixin you were using, but [my solution on this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869023/generate-random-number-in-less-css/19870741#19870741) allows you to set minimum and maximum range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check `@random` max limit as

```
.max(@number) when (@number > yourMaxLimit ) {
   @random : yourMaxLimit 
 }
```

where yourMaxLimit it should be maximum value for @random
it will set `@random` to your limit value when exceed the limit.

hope this help.