# How to pick random content from an array

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to serve a random image picked from an array in Less.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@images = ['ancora.svg', 'timone.svg', 'corda.svg', 'bussola.svg'];
@randomimage: `images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]`;
 
#footer-widgets .container .row {
    background: url("//website.com/path/@{randomimage}") no-repeat scroll right 60px bottom 40px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

I think I'm doing some syntax error though. Is that the way to call a variable inside a URL (`path/@{randomimage}`)?

Comment: Looking at your LESS I see some JS, Is that allowed? also, your LESS will be converted to CSS and CSS is static, the Image is chosen **once** when compiling the LESS.  Note: I don't use LESS and barely know about it's syntax.

Comment: According to this answer it seems possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19869095/1342772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An working example of your code can be found below:

```
@images: 'ancora.svg', 'timone.svg', 'corda.svg', 'bussola.svg';
@length: length(@images);
@random: `Math.ceil(Math.random() * (@{length}))`;
@randomimage: extract(@images,@random);

#footer-widgets .container .row {
    background: url("//website.com/path/@{randomimage}") no-repeat scroll right 60px bottom 40px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Notice that "array" in Less can be defined as lists, also see: [Loop through array of variable names in Less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-values-in-less/21441220)
**The first index of Less list is 1**

Unless you compile your Less code client side (recompile the code for every request) you should take the comment of @Random-User into account. Indeed the compiled CSS is static and the randomize do not seems the make sense.

Comment: The output is `@randomimage: extract(@images,@random);
#footer-widgets .container .row{background:url("//website.com/path/@{randomimage}") no-repeat scroll right 60px bottom 40px rgba(0,0,0,0)}`

Seems like `extract` isn't parsed. I'm using LESS pre-processor included in Jetpack by Automattic

Comment: Probably that pre-processor does not support native javascript calls at all.