# Multiple font colours for links on hover?

Tags: html, css

Is there a bit of CSS I can use that randomises the hover colour on links? For example, sometimes a user will hover over and it will be red, other times green, others blue. I know how to attach colour, I just wondered if it was possible to vary it/randomise it within a pool of colours, or whether it was limited to the one colour that you set.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider that this may be confusing to some users, who will believe there's some sort of meaning behind it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show random color on hover in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468794/how-to-show-random-color-on-hover-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript to set the color `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`. Note that setting the color to an empty string gets rid of inline color styling to revert it back to the default CSS color.

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<a onmouseenter="this.style.color = rando(['red', 'green', 'blue']).value;" onmouseleave="this.style.color='';" href="#">This is a link</a>
```

I used [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness, so make sure to add:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

in the head tag of your html document if you want to use this code.

Comment: this is so perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! If this is the solution you were looking for, please mark it with an accepted checkmark so others know you are happy with it. It will give me some points as well

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `javascript` or `jQuery` reason is explained in this answer : [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468854/11623848)

Try to do something like this which might help you can resolve your query  provided both `javascript` and `jQuery` example: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468867/11623848)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is any simple way to do this with css, but you can do this fairly easily with [jquery](https://jquery.com/).

```
<a href="#" class="random-color">Test link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="random-color">Test link 2</a>

<!-- source script for jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  // Colors array with whatever colors you want
  var colors = ['#ff8800','#ff00ff','#00ffcc'];

  // This applies a random color to the link when you hover it
  $('.random-color').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('color', colors[ Math.floor( Math.random() * colors.length ) ]);
  });

  // This function will return the color of the link to default when the mouse leaves
  $('.random-color').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#0000ee');
  });

</script>
```

[You can see the working code here.](https://jsfiddle.net/eyfudh4c/)

The links are assigned a class, in this case **random-color**, which is used to access it via the jquery selector `$('.random-color')`. the `.mouseenter` event triggers when your mouse is over the link, and then using `$(this).css()` you can apply the styles you need.

Using the `colors[ Math.floor( Math.random() * colors.length ) ]`, you assign it a random element from the colors array. You can also add, subtract, or alter any of the colors in the array.