# Is there any way to generate a random number within a given range using only CSS?

Tags: css, random, numbers

For example, something like:

```
div {
   margin-left: random(-100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use javascrtipt?

Comment: @ppperry: I can, but it just seems rather inefficient to me. There should be a way to generate random numbers in CSS, like how you can do math in it with `Calc()`.

Comment: Exactly what you're doing isn't possible in pure CSS, but [something similar is](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/BQjGzv) :P

Comment: If this was possible, then on every browser repaint the CSS might get re-evaluated and create a new random number, and your layout would move all over the place constantly, for example, when resizing the page/area or when any repaint is caused

Comment: Check out this demo https://uxdesign.cc/creating-randomness-with-pure-css-a990dafcd569

Comment: Requires a mouse click and gives the impression of being random. see https://assets.codepen.io/2722301/cards.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in pure CSS, however if you're using a CSS pre-processor, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org), then you can do the following:

```
@randomMargin: `Math.round(Math.random() * 100)`;

div {
  margin-left: ~'@{randomMargin}px';
}
```

The reason this works is because [LESS will evaluate JavaScript expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869023/generate-random-number-in-less-css).

If you want to break it into a random mixin/function, you could use:

```
.random(@min, @max) {
  @random: `Math.round(Math.random() * (@{max} - @{min}) + @{min})`;
}

div {
  .random(-100, 100);
  margin-left: ~'@{random}px';
}
```

Which will compile with a different `margin-left` value each time:

```
div {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
```

---

However, I am not sure how practical this would be in a production environment since your CSS *should* already be compiled/minified rather than compiled on the fly. Therefore you should just use straight JavaScript in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a random number as a CSS property with JavaScript:

```
let el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.style.setProperty('--rand', Math.random());
```

Then you can use that random number in your CSS, for example a random color:

```
#foo {
  --rand: 0.5; /* will be a random number from 0 to 1 set by javascript */
  --hue: calc(255 * var(--rand));
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 67%, 57%);
}
```

Or a random shade of green:

```
#foo {
  --rand: 0.5; /* will be a random number from 0 to 1 set by javascript */
  --greenHue: calc(70 + (30 * var(--rand)));
  --greenSaturation: calc(50% + (30% * var(--rand)));
  --greenLevel: calc(25% + (5% * var(--rand)));
  background-color: hsl(var(--greenHue), var(--greenSaturation), var(--greenLevel));greenLevel));
}
```

For more variation, set multiple random number variables. Also remember variables are inherited. And they can be used in keyframe animations/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Dont think CSS has that capability but LESS will help

http://csspre.com/random-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript is still an option, create the CSS dynamically upfront, as explained here:

[How to dynamically create CSS class in JavaScript and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply)