# I want to manipulate CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

in the below CSS code I want to make the size of square random which I can do with Math.random() property of Javascript but I don't know how to use it to specify size in css.

```
 #square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
    }
```

here in place of width and height specified I want it random. 
Also I want the coordinates/orientation of square to be random .
It is different from generating random numbers . generating random numbers is a part of solving this but not the complete solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to generate a random number within a given range using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704397/is-there-any-way-to-generate-a-random-number-within-a-given-range-using-only-css)

Comment: Not passible doing it entirely though CSS. But you can use some pre-processors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704397/is-there-any-way-to-generate-a-random-number-within-a-given-range-using-only-css

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. Working code.

```js
var randomWidth = Math.random()* 500;
var width = randomWidth.toString();
document.getElementById("square").style.width = width + "px";
document.getElementById("square").style.height = width + "px";
```

```css
#square {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess the OP is already about `Math.Random` and doing it through JavaScript.

Comment: @ABGR And he also advised that he is not sure how to use it.

Comment: `toString()`is not needed

Comment: @JulienMaret just in case. No harm in putting. I am aware that it works without that too. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: actually I also wanted the position to be random. i.e. the coordinate/orientation to be random can you please suggest something about that?

Comment: do you mean rotation by orientation? and the postion inside a definited space or it can go  out of the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, this will set both height and width random, if you want to set same then you can use only same random numbers:

```js
reset();
function reset(){
    reset_square();
    reset_position();
}

function reset_square() {
    document.getElementById("square").style.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100

    document.getElementById("square").style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100
}

function reset_position(){
    document.getElementById("square").style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100

    document.getElementById("square").style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100
}
```

```css
#square{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">This is custom size</div><br>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function randSize() {
  return Math.random()* 100 + 10 + "px";
}

for (var e of document.getElementsByClassName("rand")){
  e.style.width = randSize();
  e.style.height = randSize();
}
```

```css
#elem1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#elem2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#elem3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1" class="rand"></div>
<div id="elem2" class="rand"></div>
<div id="elem3" class="rand"></div>
```

Comment: actually I also wanted the position to be random. i.e. the coordinate/orientation to be random can you please suggest something about that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
reset();
function reset(){
    reset_square();
    reset_position();
}

function reset_square() {
    document.getElementById("square").style.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100

    document.getElementById("square").style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100
}

function reset_position(){
    document.getElementById("square").style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100

    document.getElementById("square").style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + "px"; 
    // returns a random integer from 1 to 100
}
```

```css
#square{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">This is custom size</div><br>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```