# Is it possible to code an accent color to change with each refresh of the website using CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, web, colors

I'm in process of experimenting to create a portfolio website, and I wondered if there's a way to set the accent color to change with each new load of the website (specifically in hue, not saturation or value).

To describe the desired result:
The website has a set dark theme, with saturated accent color designs, texts, buttons, etc.
Each time you refresh, go through a page, or re-load the page, the accent color changes in hue, from blue to pink, from pink to orange, while keeping the same value and saturation.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS you could probably just have a random number generator to choose colors from an array of accent colors i.e

```
colors = ["blue","lightblue","red","darkred"]
color = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)
root.style.setProperty('--accent-color',"color")
```

Then in css use the `--accent-color` variable for your accent colors

```
root {
  --accent-color: //insert default color;
}

.useCase {
  background-color:var(--accent-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function hsl with a fixed Saturation and Lightness, changing only the Hue with a random function, which will need LESS, something like:

```
@randomHue: `Math.round(Math.random() * 360)`;
div {
    .random(0, 360);
    background-color:hsl( ~'@{randomHue}',100%,50%);
}
```

Can find more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_hsl.asp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704397/is-there-any-way-to-generate-a-random-number-within-a-given-range-using-only-css)

Answer (score 0):

With JS and CSS, you could do something like:

```css
.my-selector {
  --hue: 0;
  background-color: hsla(var(--hue), 50%, 50%, 1);
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('.my-selector')
.style.setProperty('--hue', Math.round(Math.random() * 360))
```

If you have fixed hue's, as it seems to be the case:

```js
const hues = [25, 240, 346]

document.querySelector('.my-selector')
.style.setProperty('--hue', hues[Math.floor(Math.random() * hues.length)])
```

If it has to be nonrandom, and we need a different color on page refresh, the JS could be something like:

```js
const hues = [25, 240, 346]

function getIndex() {
  const index = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('index'))

  if (index < (hues.length - 1) && index !== null) {
    return index + 1
  }

  return 0 
}

const index = getIndex()

document.querySelector('.my-selector')
.style.setProperty('--hue', hues[index])

sessionStorage.setItem('index', index)
```

More about custom properties:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties