# Changing attribute value in CSS with a random number generator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the `animation-duration` attribute randomly (from 0 to 1) in the below css code.

```
@keyframes blink {
   50% { border-color: #ff0000; }
}
p{
    animation-name: blink ;
    animation-duration: 0.1s ;
    animation-timing-function: step-end ;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
    animation-direction: alternate ;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="label_div">
    <p id="label" class = "blink">Player #</p >
</div>
```

No Javascript used so far and I am open to use it. 
Any idea on how to do that? I had a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869023/generate-random-number-in-less-css) but I couldn't figure out how to solve my problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you *are* willing to use Javascript or not? I can't see how it would be possible without.

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to use Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your Animation is not working for me but I think this should work

```
const label = document.querySelector("p");
label.style.animationDuration = Math.random() + "s";
```

`Math.random()` will return a number between 0-1.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

btw to fix your animation just add `border: solid #000;` to your p css

Answer (score 1):

Determine a random number between 0 and your upper time-limit using:

```
var rnd = Math.Random() + UPPERLIMIT;
```

Put that code in a function, and make it execute itself after the calculated random delay:

```
function randomTimer(){
    var rnd = Math.Random() + UPPERLIMIT;
    setTimeout(randomTimer, rnd);
}
```

Then, just make sure to apply the delay to your element every cycle.

```
function randomTimer(){
    var rnd = Math.Random() + UPPERLIMIT;
    var el = document.querySelector("p");
    el.style.animationDuration = rnd + "s";
    setTimeout(randomTimer, rnd);
}
```

This will cycle your animation with a randomized duration every time.